# Show that $\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}|\int f(x)d\mu_n-\int f(x)d\mu|\to 0$, for $f\in\mathcal{F}$ equicontinuous, $\mu_n\rightharpoonup\mu$ on compact $X$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If $\mu_n\rightharpoonup\mu$ weakly on a compact metric space $X$, and if $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of equi-continuous functions, show that $\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}|\int f(x)d\mu_n-\int f(x)d\mu|\to 0$.

Here are some points that I can get to so far:

I should use Arzela-Ascoli, but I have to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is piecewise bounded, so that it is compact in $C(X)$ under the uniform norm.

Then I argue by contradiction that there exists some $f_n\in\mathcal{F}$ s.t. $|\int f_n(x)d\mu_n-\int f(x)d\mu|\ge\epsilon$. But by compactness of $\mathcal{F}$ and Arzela-Ascoli, there is a uniform convergent subsequence $f_{n_i}\to f$ in uniform norm, which will provide a contradiction.

Here are some points that I am not sure:

1. I have not used the assumption that $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$ weakly.
2. Does this result still hold if $X$ is complete and separable?

If someone can provide a rather complete version of the proof or point out where I am wrong, I will be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: I added a counter example in my answer to show that without the additional assumption of uniform boundedness your claim may be false.

Comment: Also, even if $\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}|\mu_nf=\mu f|\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$, and $\mathcal{F}$ equicontinuous, $\mathcal{F}$ may not be bounded. Consider for instance a sequence of probability measures $\mu_n$ that convergences weakly to $\mu$. The family $\mathcal{F}$  of all constant functions is unbounded and yet, $|\mu_n f=\mu f|=0$ for all $f\in\mathcal{F}$.

Answer (score 1):

When $X$ is a separable metric space and $\mathcal{F}$ is equicontinuous and uniformly bounded, this is a Theorem of R. Rao.

---

**Theorem:** Suppose $(S,d)$ is a separable metric space. Asume $\{\mu_\alpha:\alpha\in D\}$ is a net of positive measures in $\mathscr{B}(X)$ that converges weakly to $\mu$ (another positive Borel measure). If $\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly bounded and equicontinuous, then
$$\lim_\alpha\,\sup\Big\{\Big|\int f d(\mu_\alpha-\mu)\Big|:f\in\mathcal{F}\Big\}=0
$$

---

- Billingsley's book Convergence in Measure has a proof based on the Portmanteau theorem.
- Bogachev's book Measure Theory, Vol. 2 has the version of the theorem as quoted above.

---

**Edit:** Without uniform boundedness (besides equicontinuity) the statetment of the OP may fail.  Here is a **counterexample**:
Suppose $\mu_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})\mu$, where $\mu$ is a positive Borel measure on a compact set $X$ with $0<\mu(X)$. Clearly $\mu\stackrel{n\rightarrow\infty}{\Longrightarrow}\mu_n$.  The collection $\mathcal{F}$ of all positive constant functions is equicontinuous but not bounded. Then $\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}|\mu_nf-\mu f|=\frac{1}{n}\mu(X)\sup_{f\in F}|f|=\infty$.

---

Here is a proof that looks at nets (sequences will be enough if the measures are all probabilities) that I wrote in some paper:

The assumptions on $\mathcal{F}$ imply that $M:=\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\|f\|_u<\infty$;   for any $x\in X$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there is an open ball  $B_x$ centered at $x$ such that $\mu(\partial B_x)=0$ and $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ for all $y\in B_x$ and $f\in \mathcal{F}$. Since $X$ is separable, $X=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}B_{x_n}$ for some countable subcollection of balls. Set $A_1=B_{x_1}$, and $A_n=B_{x_n}\setminus\bigcup^{n-1}_{j=1}A_j$ for $n>1$. It follows that $\{A_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a pairwise disjoint collection of Borel sets covering $X$ with $\mu(\partial A_n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Define
\begin{align*}
  \nu:=\sum_n\mu(A_n)\delta_{x_n},\qquad
  \nu_\alpha:=\sum_n\mu_\alpha(A_n)\delta_{x_n}
\end{align*}
For any $\delta>0$, there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough such that $\mu\Big(X\setminus\bigcup^N_{n=1}A_n\Big)<\delta$. Since $\partial\Big(X\setminus\bigcup^N_{n=1}A_n\Big)\subset\bigcup^N_{n=1}\partial A_n$, we have that $\lim_\alpha\mu_\alpha\Big(X\setminus\bigcup^N_{n=1}A_n\Big)=\mu\Big(X\setminus\bigcup^N_{n=1}A_n\Big)$. Hence, for any $f\in\mathcal{F}$
\begin{align*}
 \left| \int_X f\,d(\nu_\alpha - \nu)\right| &\leq M \left(\sum^N_{n=1}\Big| \mu_\alpha(A_n)-\mu(A_n)\Big|  + \sum_{n>N}\Big| \mu_\alpha(A_n)-\mu(A_n)\Big|\right)\\
  &\leq M \sum^N_{n=1}|\mu_\alpha(A_n)-\mu(A_n)|+ M\left(\mu_\alpha\Big((X\setminus\bigcup^N_{n=1}A_n\Big) + \mu\Big((X\setminus\bigcup^N_{n=1}A_n\Big)\right)
\end{align*}
Passing to the  limit we obtain that
$\limsup\limits_\alpha\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}} \left| \int_X f\,d(\nu_\alpha -\nu)\right| \leq 2M\delta$. As $\delta$ may be arbitrarily small, we conclude that
$$
\lim\limits_\alpha\sup\limits_{f\in\mathcal{F}} \left| \int_X f\,d(\nu_\alpha - \nu)\right|=0.\tag{1}\label{discrete-approx-mu}
$$
Since $A_n\subset B_{x_n}$, for any $f\in\mathcal{F}$
\begin{aligned}
  \left|\int_X f\,d(\mu_\alpha-\mu)\right| &\leq \left|\int_X f\,d(\mu_\alpha-\nu_\alpha)\right| + \left|\int_X f\,d(\nu_\alpha-\nu)\right| + \left|\int_X f\,d(\nu-\mu)\right|\\
  &\leq \sum_n\int_{A_n}|f(x)-f(x_n)|(\mu_\alpha+\mu)(dx) +  \left|\int_X f\,d(\nu_\alpha-\nu)\right|\\
  &\leq\varepsilon\big(\mu_\alpha(X)+\mu(X)\big) +  \sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\left|\int_X f\,d(\nu_\alpha-\nu)\right|.\label{pre-unif-convergence}
\end{aligned}
From $\eqref{discrete-approx-mu}$ and the fact that $\lim_\alpha\mu_\alpha(X)=\mu(X)$ we get that
$\limsup_\alpha\sup\limits_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\left|\int_X f\,d(\mu_\alpha-\mu)\right|\leq 2\varepsilon\mu(X)$. The conclusion follows by letting $\varepsilon\rightarrow0$.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. But in my case $\mathcal{F}$ is not assumed to be uniformly bounded, and how to show it when $X$ is compact?

Comment: You may need boundedness of $\mathcal{F}$, for is $\mu_n\neq\mu$ (only $\mu_n\rightarrow\mu$ weakly, then take the family of all constant functions. The sup will be infinity. Even in the case of probabilities, The Kantorovich-Rubsinstein would imply  boundedness.

Comment: So that is my question: how to prove boundedness of $\mathcal{F}$, and is my argument valid when $X$ is compact?

Comment: Got it. Is my argument for $X$ compact valid? Or can I construct a similar argument you provided? Thank you!

Comment: As in the above comment, if $\mathcal{F}$ is the family of all constant functions on $X$, then $\mathcal{F}$ is equicontinuous but is not bounded. However, the boundedness of $\mathcal{F}$ is not necessary. This is because, if we fix a point $x_0 \in X$ and consider the induced family $\tilde{\mathcal{F}} = \{ f - f(x_0) : f \in \mathcal{F} \}$, then $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$ is bounded, equicontinuous, and we may essentially replace $\mathcal{F}$ by $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee: Why is $\tilde{\mathcal{F}$ bounded?

Comment: @SangchulLee Your idea works for $[0,1]$ but not for $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$.My guess is that OP's result is not even true without some extra boundedness hypothesis.

Comment: But, let me retract my claim that replacing $\mathcal{F}$ by $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}$ is enough. Now I agree that we need boundedness of $\mathcal{F}$ from the beginning. Indeed, even when $X$ is connected, if $\mu_n(X)$ are not constant, it is possible that $$\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}\left|\int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n-\int_X f\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right|=\infty.$$ For instance, this occurs when $X=[0,1]$, $\mu=\operatorname{Leb}$, $\mu_n=\frac{n+1}{n}\mu$, and $\mathcal{F}$ consists of all constant functions on $X$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, do you know where in Kellember of Bilingsley they prove this theorem?

Comment: @DaviBarreira: The attribution to Range Rao is In Billingsley (1968 edition of convergence in probability) see exercise 8, p. 17; In Dudley (Real Analysis and Probability, 1989) has the result as Corollary 11.3.4. In Bogachev (Measure theory, vol 2) The result is stated as Theorem 8.2.18. That is the version that I am quoting. Perhaps I got confused and thought that Kallenberg had a probabilistic treatment of this result.